# SharePoint 2013 - The Office HTML Viewer Service could not be registered

Tags: load-balancing, document-converter

I have Windows Server 2012 (RTM) and SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise (RTM) and SQL Server Enterprise 2012 with SP1 (RTM1).

Constantly (about every 60 seconds) I have in Application log and SharePoint ULS logs this error message:

```
03.16.2013 16:21:59.97  Microsoft.Office.Server.Convers (0x0604)    0x0948  Document Conversions    Launcher Service    7jg8    Medium  Calling LoadBalancer.RegisterLauncher   
03.16.2013 16:21:59.97  Microsoft.Office.Server.Convers (0x0604)    0x0948  Document Management Server  Document Conversions    7933    Critical    The Office HTML Viewer Service could not be registered with Office HTML Load Balancing Service.  Error:  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.  
03.16.2013 16:21:59.97  Microsoft.Office.Server.Convers (0x0604)    0x0948  Document Conversions    Launcher Service    7jgs    Medium  Loadbalancer not running or available to launcher id 1
```

I have single server and service: Document Conversions Load Balancer Service , with server hostname and default Communication Scheme: HTTP and default port: 8093

How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that SharePoint 2013 installation did not put Windows Firewall exception. I have manually added Windows Firewall rule to allow incoming TCP/8093 port and error is not appearing anymore.

Comment: Can you please mark this as an answer so that this question does not show up as unanswered :)